# Ethereum smart contract update, transactions and events

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I have a question about versioning of smart contracts in Ethereum. Lots of articles have been written about how to decouple your logic and data, how to use interfaces when referencing other contracts, how to use generic key value stores to store data and retrieving it through library functions in a strongly typed way.

What about querying transactions and event log from old versions of the smart contract? Transactions and emitted events cannot be migrated. They are immutable. And perhaps you need to keep track of them in the client app for history. Events can be added, removed or have their signature changed in different contract versions. How do you deal with querying and decoding transaction input and event data for multiple versions of a contract?

Comment: COnsider asking your question on  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each event in Solidity is internally represented by a hash of its signature. Functions are also presented by the hash.

```
let encodedFunctionSignature = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature('sendMessage(string,address)');
 console.log(encodedFunctionSignature);
 // => 0xc48d6d5e
```

The signatuare is first 32 bytes of keccak256 hash taken over by the function signature string, spaces removed.

If the event signature changes, the hash changes as well and you can distinct different ABIs for events.

Then you just need to have the matching version of ABI file to decode the event to human readable symbolic form.